# Not allowed to load local resource: <blob_url> while accessing url in content script

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to read in a local file in my content script. I am uploading a local file using file dialog at the extension popup and then sending the url to content script as a message.

I created a blob URL from a locally read file in my chrome extension's popup js, and then passed it as a message to content script, where I tried fetching it through xhr. I verified that the url was received correctly in content script and that the url when loaded in chrome has the right content. I get this error in the last line of attached code.

```
Not allowed to load local resource: blob:chrome-extension%3A//kbapkffopcceekghjelpjphdebhdkohi/9e40f540-9eb8-4ea6-ae7d-6ad52e7d2f89
```

Code :-

```
JSONFromUrl = function (url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
  console.log("success");
    };
  }
  };
  xhr.send();
};
```

I have added "file:///*" in my manifest permissions, but I am unsure if there is something I might have missed

Comment: You just can't use local files to do this. You must run your script on a webserver.

Comment: Did you mean content_scripts from chrome extensions can only access non local url ?

Comment: Go to chrome://extensions, and check "allow access to file url" on your extension.

Comment: @YoArgentino : already checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a Chrome bug, see: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=295829 - I'm trying to figure out a way to work around it too but haven't had any luck yet...

Comment: Likely. I managed to send file around as an arraybuffer, but I still feel passing a URL would have been much preferable.