# Adobe AIR and Google maps V3 icon image from local drive

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Is it possible to load a `google maps` marker image from `local hard drive`?

I tried and tried and tried but i can't just load it.

This is a very brief code that evidence the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/rPv5a/2/

Chrome console give me the following error.

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/marker.png
```

whilst, if i put the URL in the browser url bar, the marker is correctly loaded (i mean... the file exists and the local url is ok)

How can get rid of this?

**NOTE:** The `html/js` will be ran by a `StageWebView` into an Adobe AIR application, that's why i need to load an embedded marker icon image.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having a similar problem as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403347/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-blob-url-while-accessing-url-in-content-sc) question.

Can you work around it by uploading your marker image to imgur, say?