# src in html not allowed to load a local resource

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

I am doing a project, where I need to show an image on html page. The image is located in a network drive. Using the below tag to refer to the image, I receive a "Not allowed to load local resource:" error.

```
<img src="file://sc19/dept0213/SSC_Data/SVD/SVD%20Robot%20Experiment/4b9262caa1b64079ad8b31c3a3662598_1/Measurement/bot_Images/4.png" alt="Image">
```

If I however, open a new tab in the same Edge web browser, and copy the file://sc19/dept0213/SSC_Data/SVD/SVD%20Robot%20Experiment/4b9262caa1b64079ad8b31c3a3662598_1/Measurement/bot_Images/4.png into the address bar, the image is displayed inside the web browser. I have tried with Google Chrome in stead of Microsoft Edge and turned off the security feature, but still get the same error.

Additional information.
The HTML page was rendered using Django as backend. In my Django template I have.

```
<img src="file://sc19/dept0213/SSC_Data/SVD/SVD%20Robot%20Experiment/4b9262caa1b64079ad8b31c3a3662598_1/Measurement/bot_Images/4.png" alt="Image">
```

Could an alternative approach be that the front end is doing a request to the backend that then fetches the image, and put it somewhere that can be reached from front end?

Comment: Is there a web server or are you simply opening an html file?

Comment: Can you share more details how you are trying to show the image, maybe screenshot?

Comment: If you are running a webserver then you could likely create an alias that points to that network folder and access images via that alias

Comment: The webserver is running on Django as backend. Professor Abronsius can you provide me with an example of how to access the image through an alias? I have revised the question with some additional information. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I got \`Not allowed to load local resource\` error on chrome when I use blob to load resource from ArrayBuffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648553/why-i-got-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-error-on-chrome-when-i-use-blob-t) and many other answers found by searching SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my project, the solution I ended up using was for my frontend to send a request to the backend. The backend then fetches the image, and send it as a blob to the frontend. I know that setting up a webserver is another possibility, but in this case my Django backend already acts as a webserver.